# Concatenate date with character variable ,SAS

Tags: sas

I'm facing an issue where I cannot concatenate a date formatted variable with a character variable. The date format is 'date9.'. What happens is that the date turns into numbers when the concatenation is done.

Example:

Agency: RCL
Date: 24MAR2008

Result: RCL17615

It should be: RCL24MAR2008

This is my code:

```
data work.collectionrate_new;
set work.collectionrate;
tran_id=compress(agency||date);
run;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use CATT() to avoid the use of COMPRESS() as well.

Comment: Thank you. What is the difference?

Comment: CATT - removes trailing spaces automatically. CAT does not. There's a family of CAT_ type functions that do different things, check the docs for more details. http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p0wism8jqta3qmn1swtpxrs71e9a.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

Comment: Check the See Also section to see all the different functions in the family.

Comment: I see now when using CATT(), I return to the numbers problem. compress() gives the dates. I wonder why.

Comment: CAT automatically convert numbers using the BEST format, but this uses the DATE9 format so you need to manually convert it first. It's not the COMPRESS that works, its the `||` operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need a **put(date,date9.)** to format your date as character:

**Code:**

```
data new;
format  date date9. ;
date="24MAR2008"d;
agency="RCL";
tran_id=cats(agency,put(date,date9.));
put _all_;
run;
```

**Output:**

```
date=24MAR2008 agency=RCL tran_id=RCL24MAR2008
```

Comment: Assuming she is using the the compress() to remove extra spaces, then the CATT function may be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for spotting this. I've updated my code with CATS to remove both leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: As the date is already formatted as `date9` then you could also use `vvalue` instead of `put`, which returns the formatted value. `tran_id=cats(agency,vvalue(date));`